# Filter array by number in a key in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an Array here:

```
var allData: Array<Any> = Array()
```

This is what's inside the array:

```
[Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1515970800"), 
Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1515193200"), 
Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514847600"), 
Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514674800"), 
Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000"), 
Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000")]
```

A Type and a Date.

How can I filter `allData` by the `Date` so the highest number is first?

I tried this:

```
allData.sorted(by: { $0.date! < $1.date!})
```

But I get the error:

> Value of type Any has no member Date

Here's my struct:

```
import UIKit

class feedStruct: NSObject {
    var type: String?
    var date: String?

    override init()
    {
    }

    //construct with @name, @address, @latitude, and @longitude parameters
    init(type: String, date: String) {
        self.type = type
        self.date = date
    }

    //prints object's current state
    override var description: String {
        return "Type: \(String(describing: type)), Date: \(String(describing: date))"
    }
}
```

How do I filter it by the date value?

Comment: Make a proper struct/class data type to encapsulate your data with *strong* date types (`String?`, `Date?`, not `Any`), then sort that.

Comment: I already have a struct. I edited the question with it @Alexander

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `NSObject`? Just use a struct and btw it is Swift naming convention to name your classes/structures starting with an uppercase letter CamelCase `FeedStruct`

Comment: Are your properties really optionals? Do they need to mutate? Just declare them as constants. `struct Feed {
    let type: String
    let date: String }` and if you would like to implement a description property make your struct conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and don't use `String(describing:)` method to describe an optional string. Just unwrap it before doing the string interpolation. Actually you should never use that method

Comment: And change your array element type from Any to your custom struct type `[Feed]`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean

> How can I **sort** `allData` by the Date so the highest number is first

---

First of all I highly recommend to declare the custom object as **struct** with non-optional `type` and `date` and with an initializer which converts the UNIX timestamp to a `Date` instance. There is no need to use a class which inherits from `NSObject` and there is no need to use optionals.

```
struct Feed : CustomStringConvertible {

    let type: String
    let date: Date

    init(type : String, date : String) {
        self.type = type
        self.date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(date)!)
    }

    //prints object's current state

    var description: String {
        return "Type: \(type), Date: \(date))" // please do not misuse `String(describing:`

    }
}
```

---

Then declare your `allData` array as `[Feed]` (**never** as `[Any]`, that's the error reason by the way)

```
var allData = [Feed]()
```

Populate the array with `Feed` instances

```
allData = [Feed(type: "web", date: "1515970800"),
         Feed(type: "web", date: "1515193200"),
         Feed(type: "web", date: "1514674800"),
         Feed(type: "web", date: "1516590000"),
         Feed(type: "twitter", date: "1516590000"),
         Feed(type: "twitter", date: "1515970800")]
```

and sort it by date descending

```
allData.sorted{ $0.date > $1.date }
```

Comment: `struct Feed: CustomStringConvertible {`

Comment: @vadian congratulations!!! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/where-is-my-box-of-stack-overflow-swag

Answer (score 0):

```
var allData = ["15101001", "15250151", "11519501", "15192515"]
var convertedArray: [Date] = []

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

for dat in testArray {
var date = dateFormatter.date(from: dat)
convertedArray.append(date!)
}

//Method : 1
convertedArray.sort(){$0 < $1}    

//Method : 2
convertedArray.sorted(by: {$0.timeIntervalSince1970 < 
$1.timeIntervalSince1970})

print(convertedArray)
```

Comment: That is not near what I am asking for :-) I have the array `allData` with the keys type and date - they need to be there.